# What is the runtime of Quantum Fourier Sampling

Tags: asymptotics, fourier-transform

I have seen estimates for the [runtime of Shor's Algorithm,](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/16684/82867), which relies on [Quantum Fourier Transformations](https://courses.edx.org/c4x/BerkeleyX/CS191x/asset/chap5.pdf). What is the runtime of those transformations themselves?

Either big-O or more accurate estimates are welcome.

Comment: Have you explored [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_Fourier_transform)?